# CSS Positioning for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, positioning

My page is displaying properly on desktop browsers, but not on mobile devices. The url is [removed after question solved]. The logo in the top left is absolutely positioned. The divs underneath the header are also absolutely positioned with `left: 0`. Currently `div#page` has `position:relative`, but I've tried putting the relative positioning on many wrapper divs with no success. I also have php output buffers in each individual php file (e.g. header.php, body.php).

The slideshow uses a WordPress plugin that calls the jQuery Cycle plugin, and also declares absolute and relative positioning, so it may be causing confusion as to what is relative and what is absolute. But I've tried attaching relative and absolute positioning to elements in seemingly every combination and still have had no luck.

p.s. I know the CSS is a mess, I plan on going through and refactoring after I figure out this positioning issue.

Comment: And if you try with a float left?

Comment: Float left does not fix the problem. I had originally based the entire layout on the 960 grid system, floating things left of each other as they were supposed to be rendered. But I wanted to accomplish an overlap effect with the logo and the content proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a media query in there that is adding the following css at a certain break point that would be affecting the mobile size.

`#main #content {
    margin: 0 7.6%;
    width: auto;
}`

If you could clarify exactly what you feel is wrong with the mobile version it would help us give a better answer. Are you looking for the description text to bump under the slider images?

Comment: In the mobile version, all content underneath the header is pushed to the right, and the right side of the content is cut off. I think it's getting pushed by the amount of pixels dictated by my absolute positioning of the logo.

Comment: I'd like to accomplish something like `<div id="wrapper"><div id="headerContainer">logo</div><div id="contentProper">stuff</div></div>` where the header has fixed height, visible overflow, and highest z-index, so the logo appears as if it's overlapping the content.